# Convolution with Gaussian function [reference]. Let $g(x)= f(x) \star e^{-\|x\|^2}$ when is $g(x)$ is real-analytic

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, analytic-functions

I am looking for a reference to the following question, which I am sure has been studied.
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and define
\begin{align}
g(x)= f(x) \star e^{-\|x\|^2},
\end{align}
where $\star$ denots convolution operation.

What are some minimum or mild assumptions that we can make on $f(x)$ such that $g(x)$ is a real-analytic function?

I am looking for a reference or book that has such a theorem.   Note, that I am especially interested in $n>1$.

Comment: Remark that this correspond to ask what are the minimal initial conditions on the solution of the heat equation such that the solution is analytic at time $1$ (or any other time $>0$), since the solution of the heat equation is exactly the convolution with a Gaussian. This might help you to find answers. for example you have https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219928/real-analyticity-of-solution-of-heat-equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Morera's theorem if
$$F(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-(z-x)^2}dx$$
converges locally uniformly then $F$ is entire.

From there we get that if for all $c > 0$ as $r\to \infty$ $$\int_{-r}^r|f(x)|dx = O(e^{r^2-cr})$$ then $F$ is entire.

This condition is of course not necessary (try with $f(x)=(\sin(e^{e^x}))'$) and I doubt there is any minimal condition.

Comment: Does this work for  $n>1$ too?

Comment: Sure ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Is that because  Morera's theorem holds for $n>1$?

Comment: Yes it works the same way

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot